# Test recursively using mocha

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, testing, mocha.js

I have a problem with mocha, it does not understand my test hierarchy!
I want my tests to be near their codebase, so I have some hierarchy like this in my project:

```
Level1
    |_ level11
        |_ level11.js
        |_ level11.test.js
                            |_ level11111
                                |_ level11111.js
                                |_ level11111.test.js
    |_ level12
        |_ level12.js
        |_ level12.test.js
        |_ level121
            |_ level121.js
            |_ level121.test.js
Level2
    |_ level2.js
    |_ level2.test.js
```

I have tried everything! Using `**/**.test.js` or `—recursive` flag, non of them do what it should do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux to rescue! I had the same problem in a **HUGE** project that literally had no structure at all! Some developers had put tests in `tests` folder and some other in nested layers and … (some tests were using mocha and some using jest! In the SAME project! :D)

you can use:

```
mocha $(find . -name '*.spec.js')
```

in your `package.json`
so:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha $(find . -name '*.spec.js')"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `recursive` with the `extension` flag:

```
mocha --extension .test.js --recursive
```

Just read the documentation for [--extension](https://mochajs.org/#-extension-ext) and [--recursive](https://mochajs.org/#-recursive) for more.

Comment: mocha --extension .spec.js --recursive .

[ you forgot the dot at the end :) ]

Answer (score 0):

Configure your `.mocharc.js` file to allow running recursive tests as below:

```
module.exports = {
    "recursive": true,
    "exit": true,
    "timeout": "10000",
    "ignore": ["test/Helpers/*.js", "test/Samples/*.js", "test/Helpers/**/"],
    "reporter": "mochawesome",
    "reporterOptions": {
        "reportDir": "mocha"
    }
};
```